# Check cell values in two different sheets

Tags: vba, excel, cell

I have two sheets in an excel file namely bank_form and Pay_slip.
I am trying to write a vba to check whether value/text in cell B5 of sheet Pay_slip is equal to value/text in cell B8 of sheet Bank_form. Similary it will check all values till the last row of sheet Pay_slip.
But my code is not working it always comes true i.e. it always flash the message "All employees found."
Please find my mistake(s).

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim LastRow As Long
LastRow = Worksheets("Bank_form").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
LR = Worksheets("Pay_slip").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

If Worksheets("Pay_slip").Range("B5" & LR).Value = Worksheets("Bank_form").Range("B8" & LastRow) Then

MsgBox "All Employees Found."

Worksheets("Bank_form").Range("F" & LastRow + 1).Formula = "=SUM(F8:F" & LastRow & ")"

Else: MsgBox "Employee(s) missing Please check again!"

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: `Worksheets("Pay_slip").Range("B5" & LR).` This doesn't mean anything...You probably wanted to write this right ?`Worksheets("Pay_slip").Range("B" & LR).`

Comment: You post is not clear , you want to check that all values in column b in sheet `"Pay_slip"` equals cell "B8" in sheet `"Bank_form"` ? or what ? there is an offest of 3 rows between the data in the 2 sheets ?

Comment: I want to check whether value of cell B5 of sheet "Pay_slip = value of cell B8 of sheet "Bank_form" , value of cell B6 of sheet "Pay_slip = value of cell B9 of sheet "Bank_form" , value of cell B7 of sheet "Pay_slip = value of cell B10 of sheet "Bank_form"  and so on until last row of column B of sheet "Pay_slip" reached.

Answer (score 2):

you will need a loop something like this

```
Dim i as Long
For i = 5 to LastRow 'start at B5
    If Worksheets("Pay_slip").Range("B" & i).Value = Worksheets("Bank_form").Range("B" & i + 3) Then
    ' ... your other stuff here

next i
```

Answer (score 0):

```
If Worksheets("Pay_slip").Range("B5").Value = Worksheets("Bank_form").Range("B8").Value Then MsgBox "The values are the same"
```

I have no idea why you involved the number of rows in your code but they are useless in order to check the equivalence in the values in a specific cell only

Comment: It will check whether cell B5 = cell B8 of respective sheets only, I have to check cells like whether B6= B9, B7=B10, B8=B11 and so on..

Comment: Well....your post really misses from clarity. In order to do this you need either a For Loop either a Do Loop While but you won't be able to achieve this only with a simple if condition